# How do you import data from the text file to MATLAB to make cone?

Tags: c, matlab

I have a function in c and this function write data in text file. I write this function to make a cone but when I import my data in MATLAB and create mesh of it ,it doesn't look like a cone  do you know what is the problem?
which formula I use is : x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = z^z/c^c

```
int main()
```

{

```
float x,y,z,a,b,c,i,j,m,n;
FILE file;
a=1,b=2,c=3,x=-1,y=-1,i=0,j=0,n=1,m=1;
file=fopen("C:/Users/user/Desktop/test5.txt","w");
for(i=0;i<20;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<20;j++)
    {
        x=-1+(0.005)*n;
        n++;
        y=-1+(0.005)*m;
        m++;
       z= sqrt(9*x*x + (9*y*y)/4);
       fprintf(file,"%02.2f ",z);
    }
    fprintf(file,"\n");
}
fclose(file);
file=fopen("C:/Users/user/Desktop/test5.txt","a");
a=1,b=2,c=3,x=-1,y=0,i=0,j=0,n=1,m=1;
for(i=0;i<20;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<20;j++)
    {
        x=-1+(0.005)*n;
        n++;
        z=-1+(0.005)*m;
        m++;
       y= sqrt(abs((4*z*z)/9 - 4*x*x));
       fprintf(file,"%02.2f ",y);

    }
    fprintf(file,"\n");
}
fclose(file);
file=fopen("C:/Users/user/Desktop/test5.txt","a");
for(i=0;i<20;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<20;j++)
    {
        y=-1+(0.005)*n;
        n++;
        z=-1+(0.005)*m;
        m++;
       x= sqrt(abs((z*z)/9 - (y*y)/4));
       fprintf(file,"%02.2f ",x);

    }
    fprintf(file,"\n");
}
fclose(file);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to generate data in c, save into text file and then read, plot in MATLAB? You can achieve the task straight away in MATLAB. Check the below code:

```
a=1 ;
b=2 ;
c=3 ;
N = 100 ;
x=linspace(-1,1, N) ; 
y=linspace(-1,1, N) ; 
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y) ;
Z = c*sqrt(X.^2/a^2+Y.^2/b^2) ;
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

The above code generates the following plot:

[image]

YOu may have a look on the following link, it may help you futher: https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34143-meshing-thin-shells-using-four-noded-elements